# Which version of debian distro shall I install to my server?

Tags: debian, installation

This is my first time installing debian, aswell as my first experience touching a server machine. I want to install debian to my server, what version of debian shall I install ? 
Between [alpha][amd64][arm][armel][hppa][i386][ia64][mips][mipsel][powerpc][sparc] choices.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `amd64` or `i386`.

`amd64` is better, as it is 64-bit so can address more RAM. [It works](https://www.debian.org/ports/amd64/) on Intel 64-bit CPUs as well (specifically, those that have the *Intel 64* or *EM64T* extension).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I am abit confused, "Up to two (2) Quad-Core Intel® Xeon® 5400 series processors", so installing amd64 to an intel machine ?

Comment: It's just a name because amd started first on 64 bit so the port for 64 bit has been named amd64, but it also works for intel 64bit processor

Comment: It works for both, see: http://www.debian.org/ports/amd64/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your hardware. Most likely your CPU is x86 architecture and supports 64bit, you should use amd64, otherwise i386 is your distro of choice.

If you have an intel CPU, use this http://processorfinder.intel.com/ to see if it supports 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

On a Quad-Core Intel Xeon with more than 4GB RAM **always** install debian/lenny amd64.

ia64 (itanium) is not compatible with your Processor.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on experimenting heavily on server setup and configuration, might I recommend doing it with a virtual server? You can install an i386 or AMD64 version of Debian Lenny and then install either OpenVZ or VirtualServer on it. Lenny has default packages for them. It will certainly help you when you wish to experiment.